# Is there something I can do if I accidentally pressed "No Action Needed" when reviewing?

Tags: support, review-queues

So today I reviewed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/19773004) and I pressed the "No Action Needed" button by accident.
I'm pretty sure that question should be flagged.

Is there anything I can do about it? Or can I only wait until I'm banned from reviewing?

Comment: If this happens more than once, it might be a good occasion to take a quick rest break from reviewing, so as to rest your eyes / prevent accidentally slipping into "robo-reviewing" :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can just hit the back button, click the link to get to the normal view of the post, and flag it. "No action needed" is there for the purpose of review; it doesn't stop you from going back and taking (or reversing) whatever action you feel is appropriate on the post itself.

Comment: I've been guilty of doing this once or twice. In addition to flagging the post, I would also downvote, and if possible, vote to delete. In this situation, would my delete votes have counted (i.e., did it require one less reviewer to vote to delete, before it was actually deleted)?

Comment: If you're talking about the LQ review, then a delete vote from inside the queue is the same as a delete vote from outside. HOWEVER, there's a fall-back mechanism that'll "soft-delete" a post if it gets a total of *n* delete or recommend-delete *reviews*, even if the total number of delete *votes* isn't sufficient to delete the post; your vote from outside review wouldn't contribute to that.